# How can I extract href value from anchor tag and insert as text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have the html code:

```
<a href="google.com" class='link'>hi</a>
```

How do I extract href value and add it as text:

```
<a href="google.com" class='link'>hi google.com</a>
```

I've seen many posts on extracting href value but I'm not sure how to insert that as text. Thank you.

Comment: so add it to the elements text....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$('.link').text(function() {
  return $(this).text() + " " + $(this).attr("href");
})
```

**Demo**

```js
$('.link').text(function() {
  return $(this).text() + " " + $(this).attr("href");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="google.com" class='link'>hi</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jquery` `text` function

```js
$('.link').text(function(a) {
  return $(this).text().trim() + ',' + $(this).attr('href')
})
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="google.com" class='link'>hi</a>
```

With native javascript you can use `document.querySelectorAll` to get the element with common class & iterate through them and update the text

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.link').forEach((e) => {
  e.textContent = e.textContent + ' , ' + e.getAttribute('href')

})
```

```html
<a href="google.com" class='link'>hi</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the elements, use text() and read the attribute.

```js
$("a[href]").text( function (index, text){
  return text + ' ' + this.getAttribute('href')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="google.com" class='link'>hi</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in pure JS:

```js
let link = document.querySelector('.link');

link.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
   
 if (!this.classList.contains('clicked')) {
     this.innerHTML += ' ' + this.attributes.href.value;
     
     this.classList.add('clicked');
 }
});
```

```html
<a href="google.com" class='link'>hi</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this

```js
$('input:button').click(function(){
      var h = $('.link').attr('href');
      var t = $('.link').text();
      $('.link').text(t+' '+h);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="google.com" class='link'>hi</a>
 <input type="button" value="push"></button>
```